# where can i find the algorithm of these papers?

Tags: nlp

I am reading about clinical NER

I found 2 papers talking about it

[Paper 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5977567/pdf/2731659.pdf)
and
[Paper 2](https://academic.oup.com/jamia/article/18/5/601/834186)

They are talking about algorithms and ML has been used to approach clinical NER.

I could not find anywhere on how exactly these algorithms are implemented in these papers.

Can anyone help me find it or build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can email the authors to ask them if they could share their code with you, but maybe they can't for IP reasons or don't want to share it.

Papers like these are not unusual in experimental research. *In theory* you should be able to reproduce their system following the explanations in the paper.

However there are other tools available for biomedical NER: [MetaMap](https://metamap.nlm.nih.gov/), [cTakes](https://ctakes.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks mate. that helps